# Create Python C extension using MacOS 10.15 (Catalina) that is backwards compatible (MacOS10.9+)

Tags: python, macos, pypi, python-wheel, python-extensions

How can I create a Python C extension wheel for MacOS that is backwards compatible (MacOS 10.9+) using MacOS 10.15?

This is what I have so far:

```
export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
python -m pip wheel . -w wheels --no-deps
python -m pip install delocate
for whl in wheels/*.whl; do
    delocate-wheel -w wheels_fixed -v "$whl"
done
```

Unfortunately, `pip wheel` generates a file `myapp-0.0.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl`, and unlike `auditwheel` on Linux, `delocate-wheel` does not modify the name of the wheel. As a result, if I upload it on PyPI using `twine`, only users with MacOS 10.15 are able to install it using `pip`. I guess I could manually rename it to `myapp-0.0.1-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl`, but this does not sound right to me.

For the builds I am just using the GitHub Actions MacOS virtual machines.

Thank you.

PS: The compiler used for the build is GCC9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem and I will post the answer here in case someone else has the same problem.

In order to fix the problem I had to also set `export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9` before I install python using `pyenv`. Now `pip wheel` creates my wheel with the tag `macosx_10_9_x86_64`.

Thank you.

PS: When installing python via `pyenv`, python is compiled from source, and somehow it takes into account the flag `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33308902/650222), the value of `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` that the python interpreter was built with determines both the default and minimum value that can be used for wheel creation.

As you noticed, the python from `actions/setup-python` uses a relatively recent version (currently 10.14), making it incompatible with older versions. There is an open issue about this in [actions/setup-python#26](https://github.com/actions/setup-python/issues/26).

As another workaround I suggest setting up python via conda. This incurs some additional overhead (~2min) but should still be much better than building python manually. For example:

```
      - uses: goanpeca/setup-miniconda@v1
        with:
          architecture: x64
          python-version: '3.8'
          # must be explicitly specified if architecture is not x64:
          miniconda-version: latest

      - run: |
          conda create -qyf py35 python=3.5 wheel -c anaconda
          conda activate py35
          python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
        shell: bash -l {0}

      - run: |
          conda create -qyf py36 python=3.6 wheel -c anaconda
          conda activate py36
          python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
        shell: bash -l {0}

      ...
```

which will result in the following deployment targets:

- py2.7: 10.7
- py3.5: 10.6
- py3.6: 10.9
- py3.7: 10.9
- py3.8: 10.9